# Error: maybe it is overwritten before being read?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let marks: i8 = 90;
    let mut grade: char = 'N';
    
    if marks >= 90 {
        // println!("{}", grade);
        grade = 'A';
    } else if marks >= 80 {
        grade = 'B';
    } else if marks >= 70 {
        grade = 'C';
    } else if marks >= 60 {
        grade = 'D';
    } else if marks >= 50 {
        grade = 'F';
    } 
    println!("obtain grade: {}", grade)
}
```

This does not give warrning but.  below code give  warrning when i remove `else if` in last.

```
fn main() {
    let marks: i8 = 90;
    let mut grade: char = 'N';
    
    if marks >= 90 {
        // println!("{}", grade);
        grade = 'A';
    } else if marks >= 80 {
        grade = 'B';
    } else if marks >= 70 {
        grade = 'C';
    } else if marks >= 60 {
        grade = 'D';
    } else {
        grade = 'F';
    } 
    println!("obtain grade: {}", grade)
}
```

[image: warrning message]

why is this happening. The code gives warrning on else

Comment: Have you read the warning? The value assigned to `grade` is never read. It is read if you don't have `else`.

Comment: _value assigned to `grade` is never read_  in your first code there is still possibility that program output the initial value, for the latter one it is not possible

Comment: What do you mean by read? `if marks >= 90` its reading it here. or here `println!("obtain grade: {}", grade)`

Comment: To rephrase, is there any code path where you can print "N"? Answer is no, and the compiler is smart enough to figure it out. @Dogbert's answer makes a great point of underlining that in Rust, `if` is an expression, so you can do away with the initial assignement entirely.

Answer (score 6):

In the second snippet, the Rust compiler has figured out that the value in `grade` is overwritten without first reading it in every branch, which means that assigning the initial value of `'N'` is useless. To fix, you can declare the variable without a default value:

```rust
let mut grade: char;

if marks >= 90 {
    grade = 'A';
} else if marks >= 80 {
    grade = 'B';
} else if marks >= 70 {
    grade = 'C';
} else if marks >= 60 {
    grade = 'D';
} else {
    grade = 'F';
}
```

In this case, you can even omit the `mut` since every branch of the `if` assigns a value to `grade` only once:

```rust
let grade: char;

if marks >= 90 {
    grade = 'A';
} else if marks >= 80 {
    grade = 'B';
} else if marks >= 70 {
    grade = 'C';
} else if marks >= 60 {
    grade = 'D';
} else {
    grade = 'F';
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5cd02aac8c54ed8b9385a54bb7834e2f)

A more idiomatic way to do this in Rust is to return the grade from the `if` expression and assign that to `grade`:

```rust
let grade = if marks >= 90 {
    'A'
} else if marks >= 80 {
    'B'
} else if marks >= 70 {
    'C'
} else if marks >= 60 {
    'D'
} else {
    'F'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`let mut grade: char = 'N';` - there is no situation in which the 'N' value is used. It is overwritten for sure as `if else` ends with `else`. So that's why the warning